# scroll issue with A-Frame + Turbolink

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, aframe, turbolinks

I'm using Rails 5.1.4 with Turbolinks. On one of my pages I have an A-Frame 0.7.0 scene. I found something weird happening:

Step to reproduce:

1. open a page and scroll the content
2. click a link to a page where there is A-Frame `a-scene` (see below)
3. go back to the previous page... now you cannot scroll the page anymore.

The scene is very simple:

```
<a-scene id="about--a-scene" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded>
    <a-assets>
        <img id="cover-image" src="some/path/to/image" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </a-assets>
    <a-sky src="#cover-image"></a-sky>
    <a-camera fov="50"></a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

I guess it's something related with the scroll event, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Does it happen to any page or some particular page? You might need to show what that previous page is if it was latter. How do you go back? Click a link or browser back button?

Comment: I use internal links which by default are "turbolinked". It happens to a normal page only after if I've visited a page with aframe embedded. If I remove the `a-scene` tag everything works smoothly.

Comment: Probably A-Frame has some JS code preventing scrolling which is persisted to the new page due to turbolinks. Did you try disabling turbolinks for that link?

Comment: That's what I thought. I can try, but it generates some inconsistency with the UX (namely the header animates again). I'll start an issue ticket on AFrame to see how that can be solved.

Comment: I would imagine disabling turbolinks on one link shouldn't affect the rest of the page.